# WinForm WebBrowser Control slow to load

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have used a web browser control to show HTML text in my win-form pop up:

```
webBrowserCharges.DocumentText ="HTML string";
```

But when open first time it is taking too much time. When I click again it is showing data quickly.

in winform i have written below code to fetch data and show in web browser control

```
DataSet DsPaymentReceipt;
DsPaymentReceipt = _wbSrv.GetTESTDATA("TEST DATA", FromDt, ToDt);
if (DsPaymentReceipt != null && DsPaymentReceipt.Tables.Count > 0 && DsPaymentReceipt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                webBrowserCharges.DocumentText = Convert.ToString(DsPaymentReceipt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StrXml"]);
            }
```

but above code is not taking time to fetch or assignment of Dataset values.

Why it is taking time at first time, I can't figure out.

Comment: Could you show us more code, because I don't think the problem in the code you shown us.

Comment: in code debugger is not stopping anywhere. it  takes time at this line "frm.ShowDialog();"for first time

Comment: Yes, but what's ``FrmViewLog();``

Comment: Its my Win-Form name. I have just initialized it.

Comment: "But when open first time it is taking too much time. When I click again it is showing data quickly." , which data ? Do you understand what  I mean ? You can't have only ``frm = new FrmViewLog();
frm.ShowDialog();`` and ``webBrowserCharges.DocumentText =some data;``

Comment: i have edited question as per your suggestion.

Comment: I think he want to say that web browser control which loads HTML String takes time to load first time,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need only to Ngen your exe

```
public static void NgenApplication()
    {
        if (!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed || !ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun) return;

        string appPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string winPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");

        using (var proc = new Process())
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(appPath);

            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = $@"{winPath}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"uninstall {Application.ProductName} /nologo /silent";

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = $@"{winPath}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"install {Application.ProductName} /nologo /silent";

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```